# Changing items value via onclick isn't working

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, getelementbyid

Could anyone tell me why the below code isn't working?

```
<input type="hidden" name="way" mode="way" value="" />

<input type="button" name="finish" value="Update & Finish" onclick="document.getElementById('way').value='continue'; document.edit_list.submit();" />
```

I get the error:

```
Error: document.getElementById("way") is null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` and `id` are different attributes.  Your input doesn't have an `id` defined.

Comment: Ahh crap thx for that...... I had it called 'mode' instead 'way' previously & accidentally must have used 'mode' instead of 'id' lol

Answer (score 1):

The element with the name property of "way" also needs an id property.

```
<input type="hidden" name="way" mode="way" id="way" value="" />
```